# Using Multiple Defined Variables In MYSQL Connect

Tags: php

I wish to allow a user to login to their MySQL database. Their username and end of the SQL database is the same, however each Database name starts with;
linkycra_[username]

I'm attempting to use defined variables in connecting to the SQL.

It would work with a comma in an echo - however obviously, commas cannot be used in this format.

http://puu.sh/1IBJP.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [concatenation operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php).

Answer (score 0):

Well, there is a lot of thing to fix in your code.

First, don't use an image to paste code, but directly in stackoverflow or if it's too long, in a pastebin-like website.

Then, you should not use mysql_* methods since they are deprecated (read [the doc](http://php.net/mysql_connect)), but [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) instead.

Next, you should never use the value in the cookie directly like this. You must verify it, sanitize and filter it, to be sure the value returned is correct : I can modify this value and with some work, maybe hack your website. Not a good way.

Then, if it's `lynkycra_[username]`, you can use the concatenation of strings (based on your code) :

```
$link = mysql_connect('server', 'linkycra_'.$_COOKIE['monlotronloggedin'], 'password');
```

See ?